# "He/she and Name" and "name and I"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure, phrase-structure

I often see the he/she and [name] constructions. But I think I've never seen the I and [name] construction. Examples:

> Tom averted Mark's eyes. Were **he and Mark** still in unfriendly terms?
>
> Tom averted my eyes. Were **Tom and I** still in unfriendly terms?

Is this the case? Is there a reason?

Comment: It is mainly so because putting yourself before others is sought upon as impolite or discourteous. I don't know if their is another reason as such. Also it should be _[...] **on** unfriendly terms._ Also, we cannot avert someone else's eye. Hence it should be _Tom averted his eyes/gaze from Mark. [...]_

Comment: Did you mean to use __avoided__ instead of _averted_ in the context?

Comment: Increasingly today people would avoid the cited examples in favour of *Were **him and Mark** still friends?* and *Were **me and Tom** still friends?* Note that if only one of the two people is being referenced by a ***pronoun***, that will nearly always be specified first. But if they're *both* pronouns, there's little to choose between, say, *Are **you and me** still friends?* and *Are **me and you** still friends?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica - I disagree strongly with your first two examples. They are ungrammatical and would be picked up immediately by any editor.  Also an examiner would deduct marks. With regard to *"Are you and me still friends?"*, yes, I agree,  people do say this conversationally although I personally would say, *"Are you and I still friends?"* because I still have some respect for grammar. However that last example (direct speech) was not the question. The question was indirect.

Comment: @chasly: I assume prescriptive Victorian grammarians took exception to forms like ***him and me*** because it didn't fit with their attempts to shoehorn English into *Latin* categories and inflections. So [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=him+and+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) shows how it steadily fell out of favour (having been perfectly common and natural until a couple of centuries ago). But in the last 2-3 decades it's been making a big comeback in print (it was always kept in *speech*, just dismissed as "common" by many such as yourself).

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: Even if as many as ***half*** the NGram hits were pedants advising against the usage, that would still support my case that it's ***increasing***. They wouldn't feel moved to put their advice into print if they weren't bothered about the extent to which more and more people "ignore the rules". But I agree with your point that *learners* (including even native speakers) need to be careful here - it's one of those cases where you might have to choose between learning to speak like the natives, and *passing an exam*. Or at least, be aware of that potential difference.

Comment: P.S. There is no Victorian prohibition against "him and me". I use it myself. However I use it as the object of a verb, not the subject.  I would not personally say, "Him and me like the cinema." any more than I would say the Tarzan-like "Me like the cinema".  However I would, as a highwayman, say, "Give him and me all your money". The Victorians would be perfectly okay with this because it accords with "Give me your money".  Few except perhaps a pirate says "Give I your money"  (actually I think they say this in the West COuntry and in the Caribbean)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica - I don't disagree. I am aware of the difference and I often say so explicitly.  My main intention is however to give an  answer and, if possible, a "rule" that produces something that is definitely correct by examiners' standards.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: I don't see how you can baldly assert *There is no Victorian prohibition against "him and me"*. Putting aside the (erroneously inherited from classical Latin, imho) nominative / accusitive distinction as it applies to subject / object, how else do you explain the steady decline of ***him and me*** from 1820 to 1980? You've also got to account for that sudden massive *reversal* of the decline in recent decades (where there are almost certainly far more ***informal*** usages appearing in print simply because of changing attitudes to what we do and don't print today).

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: There are still many aspects about English (and language in general) that I can learn from this site. But "correct" use of English isn't one of them. I know what I say and what I hear, and at my age with a degree in English+French Lang & Lit + Linguistics, that's good enough for me. My *view* is that people do in fact increasingly use what are still being called "incorrect" forms in this area, but I probably won't live long enough to see those forms cease to generate controversy.

Comment: *"correct" use of English isn't one of [the aspects]"* - For you maybe not, but for many, if not most, of the learners here, "correct" English is of prime importance. It enables them to pass exams with the highest possible marks. Good exam results can make all the difference between success and failure when applying to colleges and universities  in an English-speaking country for example.  The sort of English they are expected to know does not include regional dialects or common informal conversational English.

Comment: P.S. Your nGram does not so convincingly show a trend for "him and me" when you compare its shape with that of "he and I".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=him+and+me%2Che+and+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chim%20and%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20and%20I%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chim%20and%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20and%20I%3B%2Cc0  Rather the opposite I would say.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica:  Well, you do have to [include "me and him" along with "him and me"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28him+and+me%2Bme+and+him%29%2Che+and+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28him%20and%20me%20%2B%20me%20and%20him%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20and%20I%3B%2Cc0) to compare like with like (the corresponding form "I and he" being virtually non-existent). But I take your point that it's not such good supporting evidence as it looks at first. It still reflects an actual trend though, imho. You other point I already agreed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Tom averted Mark's eyes. Were he and Mark still in unfriendly terms?
>
> Tom averted my eyes. Were Tom and I still in unfriendly terms?

Firstly we must correct some mistakes.

1. It is only possible to avert one's own eyes. You cannot avert someone else's eyes. (except perhaps by some unpleasant use of force).  As @Dhanishtha Ghosh says, the word you need is "avoided"
2. We are said to be "on" friendly or unfriendly terms, not "in".

Now we have

> Tom avoided Mark's eyes. Were he and Mark still on unfriendly terms?
>
> Tom avoided my eyes. Were Tom and I still on unfriendly terms?

Those are both perfectly correct.

---

In response to comment by @rjpond

Normally in standard grammar we use the polite form by always putting ourselves last, e.g.

"Tom and I went to school" is considered politer, and more conventional, than "I and Tom went to school". Note that some examiners will insist on it.

If there is a list of people then we still put ourselves last, e.g.

"Martha, Tom, Ben and I went to school."

This also applies with "me".

"The man shouted at Tom and me" is considered more "correct" than "The man shouted at me and Tom."